# Problem burning .img into SDHC card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

First of all, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I was trying to write the Raspbian.img file into a 32GB Sandisk microSD following [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md). After executing the command, my sdcard was on `/dev/sdc` and the raspbian.img was in the file rp.img. After executing this command: `sudo dd bs=4M if=rp.img of=/dev/sdc` it told me that the sd card didn't have enough space, and the sdcard ended up having just 60MB.

I used Windows with a special program which formatted my card to 32GB again, and in fat32. And tried to burn the .img into the sdcard from windows, with the same results. Each time I try to run that command (on Linux) or burn the image in Windows, I have the same error! Also tried to burn the .img in Windows, but I had the same problem.

Now my card is not recognized by any computer (tried 2 different computers and 3 different readers). When I run `sudo fdisk -l` in Linux, I get this output:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 28.8 GiB, 30908350464 bytes, 60367872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem? Should I buy a normal SD card and not a microSD?

Trying to write `/dev/zero` has the same result:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: Input/output error  <=>  ]
0+14069 records in
0+14068 records out
1129185280 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 16.7988 s, 67.2 MB/s
1.05GiB 0:00:19 [55.9MiB/s] [  <=> ]
```

Comment: I would first zero the card out using `sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` (make sure that `/dev/sdc` is the sd card you want to overwrite - all data on it will get destroyed!). What size does it report after having finished? After that try to write the image again.

Comment: Isn't /dev/zero infinite? How will I know when it ends?

Comment: `/dev/zero` produces an infinite amount of zero-bytes. `dd` will stop as soon as `/dev/sdc` is full.

Comment: Updated the question with more info, trying to write /dev/zero has the same result...

Comment: Is your SD card reader able to manipulate SDHC cards?

Comment: The `Input/output error` suggests that your SDHC card is broken and needs to be replaced. Oh, and where did you buy the card? It could also mean that the card does only declare to be 32GB big but is actually much smaller (you would have been tricked). However, as you say the size varied, I think it's more likely that some memory cells are dying.

Comment: Sounds like a defective card to me as well.

Comment: It's a sandisk card and if I format it in fat32 i can use it with the Sony camera perfectly. Also, i tried different readers which let me see the photos when I used the sd in the camera. That's what's bothering me...